# How to import every image with file-loader on React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

me and my colleagues using React-boilerplate.

When we want add image we need to do two processes.

1. Add image on **assets** folder.
2. import image on **app.js** like this. 
   `import '!file-loader?name=[name].[ext]!./assets/icon/icon_truck.svg';`

So, if I want add three images, I need to three import lines. 
`import '!file-loader?name=[name].[ext]!./assets/icon/icon_truck1.svg';` 
`import '!file-loader?name=[name].[ext]!./assets/icon/icon_truck2.png';` 
`import '!file-loader?name=[name].[ext]!./assets/icon/icon_truck3.jpg';`

I think this is inefficient.

But I don't know how to add every image file...

How to import all specific extension(png, jpg, svg...) files in the **assets** folder?

I cant' find webpack.config.js in our project..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Webpack V5**:

- Use [require.context()](https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/#require-context) to load all modules in a directory dynamically. This means you can load all `.svg` modules dynamically. You don't have to `import` them one by one.
- `file-loader` is `DEPRECATED` for v5, migrate to [Asset Modules](https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-modules/) to allows one to use asset files (fonts, icons, etc) without configuring additional loaders.

Directory structure:

```sh
⚡  tree -L 5 -I 'node_modules'
.
├── dist
│   ├── app.js
│   ├── icon_truck1..svg
│   ├── icon_truck2..svg
│   └── icon_truck3..svg
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
├── src
│   ├── app.js
│   └── assets
│       └── icon
│           ├── icon_truck1.svg
│           ├── icon_truck2.svg
│           └── icon_truck3.svg
└── webpack.config.js

4 directories, 11 files
```

`src/app.js`:

```js
function importAll(images) {
  images.keys().forEach((image) => {
    console.log(image);
  });
}

const images = require.context("./assets/icon", true, /\.svg$/);
importAll(images);
```

`webpack.config.js`:

```js
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  mode: "development",
  entry: "./src/app.js",
  output: {
    filename: "app.js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    publicPath: "",
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(png|svg)$/i,
        type: "asset/resource",
        generator: {
          filename: "[name].[ext]",
        },
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

Execution result:

```sh
⚡  node dist/app.js
./icon_truck1.svg
./icon_truck2.svg
./icon_truck3.svg
```

Since you are using `React-boilerplate`, try to use `require.context()` like above directly.